# Multiprocessing for Python parallelization error - "function' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, gpu, joblib, multi-gpu, tesla

We have **NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU accelerator computing** in our data center with the following characteristics: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v3 @2.30GHz, 48 CPU processors, 128GB RAM, 12 CPU cores`running under Linux 64-bit.

I am running the following code which does `GridSearchCV` after vertically appending different sets of dataframes into a single series of data for a `RandomForestRegressor` model. As an example, the two sample datasets I am considering are found in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUcVR2Q2xQQzlvTWM)

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
import sys
import imp
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import math
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "cubic*.csv"))), ignore_index=True)
#df = pd.read_csv('cubic31.csv')

for i in range(1,3):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = (pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['X'].shift(i) for i in range(3)}).apply(np.nan_to_num, axis=0).values)

X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)

X_train = X_train.drop('time', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('time', axis=1)


print(X.shape)
print(df['Y'].shape)

print()
print("Size of X_train:",(len(X_train)))
print("Size of Y_train:",(len(X_train)))
print("Size of X_test:",(len(X_test)))
print("Size of Y_test:",(len(y_test)))

print()

def gridSearchCVParallel():
    #Fit models with some grid search CV=5 (not to low), use the best model
    parameters = {'n_estimators': [10,30,100,500,1000]}
    clf_rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)
    clf = GridSearchCV(clf_rf, parameters, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
    model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model.cv_results_['params'][model.best_index_]
    math.sqrt(model.best_score_*-1)
    model.grid_scores_

    #####
    print()
    print(model.grid_scores_)
    print("The best score: ",model.best_score_)

    print("RMSE:",math.sqrt(model.best_score_*-1))

    #reg = RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mse')
    clf_rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    modelPrediction = clf_rf.predict(X_test)
    print(modelPrediction)

    print("Number of predictions:",len(modelPrediction))

    meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y_test, modelPrediction)
    print("Mean Square Error (MSE):", meanSquaredError)
    rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(meanSquaredError)
    print("Root-Mean-Square Error (RMSE):", rootMeanSquaredError)


    ####### to add the trendline
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    #df.plot(x='time', y='Y', ax=ax)
    ax.plot(df['time'].values, df['Y'].values)


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    index_values=range(0,len(y_test))

    y_test.sort_index(inplace=True)
    X_test.sort_index(inplace=True)

    modelPred_test = clf_rf.predict(X_test)
    ax.plot(pd.Series(index_values), y_test.values)


    PlotInOne=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.Series(modelPred_test), pd.Series(y_test.values)], axis=1))

    plt.figure(); PlotInOne.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
NumberOfCores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

gridResults = Parallel(n_jobs=NumberOfCores)(delayed(gridSearchCVParallel))

print(gridResults)
```

When I finally run this program for a huge dataset (around 2 million rows), it is taking more than 4 days to do the `GridSearchCV`. After a bit of search, I found out that `Python` threads can utilize more than one CPU using either `concurrent.futures` or `multiprocessing`. As it shown in my code, I tried to make use of `multiplrocessing` but I am getting this error `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`. This seems that the function should take a single parameter as an input and we pass in an iterable as the argument. How can I fix this issue so as to utilize more than one CPU and do the task faster in a short period of time?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** attempt to parallelize this on your own. Do *not use* `joblib.Parallel`. You will be reinventing the wheel, anyway, since [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) is *already-parellized*. Just pass `n_jobs` parameter, which defaults to `1`, i.e. it defaults to using a single job. To take advantage of multi-core architecture, pass `n_jobs = number_of_cores`, where `number_of_cores` is the number of cores you want to use.

And if you check the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L627), you'll see it basically wraps a call to [joblib.Parallel](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.Parallel.html), so `n_jobs=-1` should work for "all cores".

Comment: "Just pass n_jobs parameter, which defaults to 1" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos read the linked documentation. But I added a little bit to the answer.

Comment: @roganjosh yeah, I'm pretty sure `-1` would work, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

Comment: @roganjosh indeed, see the edit, it just passes that parameter through to `joblib.Parallel`, so it should work with `-1`

Comment: what do you mean by `n_jobs=-1`? The error i mentioned arises when i do `gridResults = Parallel(n_jobs=NumberOfCores)(delayed(gridSearchCVParallel))` and it is because the function `gridSearchCVParallel()` expects one argument.

Comment: even if i do that - `n_jobs=48`, it is taking so long to produce an output

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos my point was that you shouln't be using `joblib.Parallel`, the `GridSearchCV` constructor takes a `n_jobs` argument, because `GridSearchCV` is *already parallelized*. You probably aren't going to write something that beats it's implementation. And note, none of this will take advantage of your GPU. Does the machine you are working on have 48 cores? Because if it has less, then it will likely work *slower* than serial.

Comment: Yes, i get that but if we pass `n_jobs` argument to `GridSearchCV` - will it take advantage of our GPU? I mean do you think it will run faster? Thank you so much for the explanations by the way. Accepting your answer!

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos no - none of these approaches will take advantage of your GPU. You would have to write code using something like Cuda or OpenGL to use the GPU directly, your code doesn't just port directly over to a completely different architecture.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought it would be faster if we run it on multiple cores.

Comment: @DestaHaileselassieHagos it still might be. It just might not be faster by enough. Note, grid-search works in polynomial time.